# Dagger - interface binding in separate module cannot be resolved

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I have a question about the dagger. I have an Android module which provides APIs so basically a bunch of interfaces. Like

```
interface Paying {
    fun pay(amount: Double)
}
```

I have a separate module in which the implementation for above interface lies

```
class Purchase @Inject constructor() : Paying {
    override fun pay(amount: Double) {
        // Implementation logic here
    }
}
```

The impl module has following binding between interface and implementation class

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
abstract class PayingModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindPayingApi(impl: Purchase): Paying
}
```

Doing above I am getting the error `cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method` but
If I move the interface and implementation in the same module, then the error resolves. Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: Faced the same issue, looked like Hilt did not generate implementation of `Factory<Paying>` (it generated one for `Factory<Purchase>` because of the `@Inject` annotation). Switched to `@Provides` instead of `@Bind` and it created `Factory<Paying>` in `<project-with-the-module-definition>/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/<your.package>/di/xxx_<provide-method-name>Factory.java`.